# Postfix relay for gmail sending as root

Tags: postfix, gmail

I've configured postfix to relay gmail (google apps) but the emails are sending as root@example.com instead of admin@example.com as (I believe) I've configured. I think the config is ok because I'm not getting any error. The issue is that it tries to send as root which doesn't exist! How can I get the emails to send as admin@example.com as I specified in my sasl_password file and db?

For all config/logs, I've removed my domain and replaced with example.com.

Maillogs

```
Oct  1 13:40:57 mon1 postfix/qmgr[5449]: C01AD22880: from=<root@example.com>, size=450, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  1 13:40:57 mon1 postfix/local[5456]: C01AD22880: to=<admin@domain>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

sasl_password

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 admin@example.com:MYPASSWORD
```

/etc/aliases (no tutorials suggested this, just one of the things I've tried)

```
#PostFix
root:       admin@example.com
```

additions to main.cf

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
# enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication. 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption 
smtp_use_tls = yes
# where to find CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

Comment: you can use sender_canonical_maps for masquerade the outgoing mails

Comment: Also, note that changes to the /etc/aliases files (at least for postfix, not sure about sendmail) require: /bin/newaliases ; service postfix restart #(or whatever you use to restart postfix on your distro).  That aliases change ensures emails *to* root on your system get sent to admin@mydomain instead. Then, @c4f4t0r's answer ensures that the *from* message is also set to something valid, since some servers (e.g. Amazon SES) will reject the default root@localdomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use sender_canonical_maps for masquerade the outgoing mail, in you main.cf

sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical

```
echo "root admin@mydomain" >> /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

after that, reload your postfix service

Comment: Thanks very much, that's definitely worked as far as ensuring the sender is correct, unfortunately the mails aren't coming through though!